# Junit coverage for exception in the finally block

Tags: exception, mockito, response, junit4, finally

I'm trying to mock the close method inside the finally block. so that the Exception also gets covered in the coverage.

```
Respose response = null;
.....
finally {
  try {
    response.close();
  }catch (IOException exp) {
    System.out.println(exp);
  }
}
```

SOP is not getting covered in the junit coverage.

*Unit test snippet*:
[image]

Comment: Is your problem that you can't mock the void method?

Comment: Mocking void methods: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12